# Adapter with condition

Tags: android, android-adapter

It is possible to put an if/else statement in an adapter?   Here's the code:

```
public void viewentry() {
    EntryList = controller.getAllEntry();
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        MainActivity.this, 
        EntryList,
        R.layout.timeline,
        new String[] { "Id", "title", "content", "date", "time", "category", "tag", "location", "mood" }, 
        new int[] { R.id.Id, R.id.title, R.id.content, R.id.date, R.id.time, R.id.category, R.id.tag, R.id.location, R.id.mood }
    );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to set visibility of my textview. If the title is empty, then it will gone in timeline else it will visible.

Comment: Yes it's possible. In a custom adapter `getView()`, set view visibility conditionally. Brontok's answer gives some code towards that direction.

Comment: @laalto I tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible , But you need to create your own custom adapter for the list.

Go through this tutorial for creating custom Adapter [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Below is an example

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = values[position];

    if (s.startsWith("Windows7") || s.startsWith("iPhone")
        || s.startsWith("Solaris")) {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

check this inside the getView method of adapter **R.layout.rowlayout**

Here you need to create a custom layout(rowlayout) for list then find the id of your repsective TextView  and do whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to set visibility of textview. If the title is null then in my timeline the title textview will gone. If there is a title then it will visible. How can I do that?

Comment: Thank you. I will back when it's ok

Comment: Hi. Can you help me? I'm stuck.

Comment: @Haj Yes, Tell me your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since SimpleAdapter isn't final, you can extend from it:

```
public void viewentry() {
    EntryList = controller.getAllEntry();
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        MainActivity.this, 
        EntryList,
        R.layout.timeline,
        new String[] { "Id", "title", "content", "date", "time", "category", "tag", "location", "mood" }, 
        new int[] { R.id.Id, R.id.title, R.id.content, R.id.date, R.id.time, R.id.category, R.id.tag, R.id.location, R.id.mood }
    ) {

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            v.findViewById(R.id.mood).setVisibility(condition ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            return v;
       }
    };
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

}

Comment: Why it get's error? ViewGroup parent, condition, setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Should I create new class for ViewGroup? and create field for condtion?

Comment: I changed the ViewGroup to android.view.ViewGroup. It is ok?

Comment: You can just `import android.view.ViewGroup`, but yeah that works as well.

Comment: It doesn't show Import so I choose create new class for ViewGroup. And I just tested it, but doesn't work.

Comment: I'm stuck. Can you help me?